# Подтверждение платежа при оплате через QIWI форму на Python

Tags: python

как реализовать подтверждения платежа, реализованного через форму оплаты QIWI. Бот оптравляет ссылку на форму оплаты, юзер подтверждает оплату, и бот должен вывести информацию в чат о том что платеж произведен успешно.

Comment: Форма оплаты Ваша? В коде? Или форма на сайте?
Нужно больше информации.

Comment: форма оплаты на сайте QIWI

Comment: Alik есть чужой сайт, в данном случае qiwi. Что дальше?

Вы оплачиваете на сайте, значит не парсите сайт, а данные через браузер. 
При чём тут тогда python? Что вы хотите сделать?
Вы хотите, чтобы выводилось "Платёж прошёл", выводилось куда, в каком формате? Чтобы Вам помогли надо указывать больше информации. Сидеть и догадываться никто не будет.

Comment: К сожалению, после отправки формы на сайт qiwi для оплаты, бот никак не сможет контролировать - оплатил пользователь платёж, или нет, кроме как по API qiwi. 

В этом случае, советую Вам использовать API от qiwi, где можно использовать веб хуки для получения данных. [qiwi]https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#quick_hook